# transforming/manipulating result of a tsql join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataset like the following:

```
dataset1:
 **columns:** id  type  loc  x_qty  y_qty  z_qty  j_1   j_2   date
 **row: **   1   fe    32   292    394    112    NULL  NULL  2012-09-21
 **row: **   2   fd    30   298    394    112    NULL  NULL  2012-09-22
 **row: **   3   fc    31   343    394    112    NULL  NULL  2012-09-23
```

and I'm left joining `dataset2` onto `dataset1` on `type`, `loc`, and `date` to get `j_1` and `j_2`

```
dataset2:
**columns:** id  type  loc  x_qty  y_qty  z_qty  j_1   j_2   date
**row: **    1   fe    32   NULL   NULL   NULL   239   349   2012-09-21
**row: **    2   fe    31   NULL   NULL   NULL   209   319   2012-09-23
```

My problem is that `dataset1` has a row for every single day, while `dataset2` only has rows for days that `j_1` and `j_2` have values. So for the ending dataset, there will be a NULL in `j_1` and `j_2` for every date that does not exist in `dataset2`.

My question: Is there a way, to put the value for the previous date in the column if there is no date. For example, using the datasets above. `9-22` does not exist in `dataset2`, so there will be a the `9-22` row in the final result, with NULLs in `j_1` and `j_2`, is there a way to use the previous date's values of `j_1` and `j_2` and put them in that row?

Thanks in advance for any help!

SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Suggest you add what version of SQL Server you're working with - later versions have features that might make this easier.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use something like this to join with the current or previous date?

SELECT *
FROM dataset1 t1 
INNER join dataset2 t2 ON t2.date = (select MAX(t3.date) from dataset2 t3 where t3.date <= t1.date)

Comment: I like this. It is very concise, and expresses the solution well. Nicely done.